# Vb.net, I hope to make a small program

Tags: vb.net

I watched many videos on Youtube, Read many articles and topics on this matter,
I've used Stopwatch function to compare between them, could not reach any result.

Which will make my program small?
I know that the second example is easy to understand

Ex 1:

```
Dim WB As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient
Dim R As String = WB.DownloadString("")
IO.File.WriteAllText("FinalResult", R)
```

Ex 2:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

        Dim WB As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim R As String = WB.DownloadString("")
        File.WriteAllText("FinalResult", R)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that many code snippets will execute so quickly that you can't time the difference between them, even if one is significantly faster. You often need to put the code being tested inside a loop in order to execute in a large number of times. Significant relative differences can then become apparent. While writing efficient code is always a good thing, unless there's a noticeable impact on performance, readability and maintainability should be higher priorities.

Comment: As a general rule, even experienced programmers are terrible at guessing low-level efficiency a priori; if you want an example, look at Eric Lippert's blog, he's got some examples in a recent series on Life.  Focus on making sure your algorithms are efficient and you're using the right data structures, and only dive into the lower-level details when you have a confirmed need more performance (and use a profiler when you do).

Comment: At that, the Life series is also a great example of the importance of choice of algorithm.  An inefficient linear algorithm will still beat the pants off a highly-optimized quadratic algorithm on large data sets.

Comment: Worry about creating reliable, bugs free and readable application, because those types of applications don't jam if they are bigger or inefficient if they were smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between those two code snippets once compiled. It is purely a matter of readability. Given that you should always strive for the most readable code, the second option is better from that perspective.

You should also keep in mind that, unlike C#, VB allows you to import namespaces at the project level too. If you want to use types from a namespace in multiple code files, it's generally preferable to import them at the project level, which you do on the References page of the project properties.

Importing namespaces that you use multiple times and importing namespaces at the project level that you use in multiple files are both implementations of the DRY principle, i.e. Don't Repeat Yourself.